# How to disable previous days in calendar in flutter?

Tags: datetime, flutter, datepicker

I have a datepicker in flutter. Now I need to disable all the previous days from present date in calendar in flutter. When I tried to do , it only disable the one previous day.
If someone can try this, it will be helpful.

```
final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
    selectableDayPredicate: (DateTime val) =>
    val.day == DateTime.now().day - 1 ? false : true,
    context: context,
    initialDate: DateTime.now(),
    firstDate: new DateTime.now().subtract(new Duration(days: 30)),
    lastDate: DateTime(2101));
```

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: package:flutter/src/material/date_picker.dart -- its an inbuilt date picker in flutter.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I got the solution as this for my question, might be useful for someone.
If it helped anybody then accept my answer as correct.

```
final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1)),
  lastDate: DateTime(2100),
);
```

Comment: good answer, we can replace Duration(days: 1) with Duration.zero !

Answer (score 2):

Better Answer is below it will disable **previous** **dates**

```html
final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 0)),
  lastDate: DateTime(2100),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

for disabling future dates just set lastDate to present date which disable every date after current date

```
 await showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: _selectedDate,
  firstDate: DateTime(1850),
  lastDate: DateTime.now(),
);
```

and for diabling previous date set firstDate to current date which disable every date before current date

```
 await showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: _selectedDate,
  firstDate:DateTime.now(),
  lastDate: DateTime(2050),
);
```